# In jQuery, how to set the position of a element in percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent, css-position

How to get the click event position in percentage and how to pass this value to element via 
jQuery? When I pass via the `.css()` method, it pass always as pixels.

The events `e.pageX` and `e.PageY` return the values in pixels. I can calculate the percentage, but if there is some way to get in percentage, I will use it.

The main problem is passing the values as percentage to the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no pre-calculated percentage property.

```
$('element').click(function(e){
    var percent = e.pageX / $(window).width() * 100;
    $(this).css('left',percent + '%');
});
```